# How to solve Chart js mismatched x-axes label and value dynamically in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, chart.js, bar-chart, mismatch

I have encountered a problem using chart js when applying it dynamiccally, which means I get a data from my database and output a bar graph using Chart JS. I found this example which works when a value is 0, but on my situation some data on a specific year cannot be found yet on my database, which leads to a null value. How can I set this empty or null value to zero so that I can achieve this example [https://jsfiddle.net/17mw40rx/1/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2iSB.png). I want also to show my JS code which I copied from the same sample and applied it to my project. The script works fine but when a year data is missing let say no record found in 2002 and 2005, the data are filled automatically by a wrong year data. I hope you understand my problem. Please I need help from someone about this.

JS Script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script>

var year = ['2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020'];
var female = <?php echo $female; ?>;
var male = <?php echo $male; ?>;

var entranceDataset = {
              label: 'Female',
              type: 'bar',
              yAxesID : "y-axis-1",
              data: female,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 204, 0, 0.2)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(0, 204, 0,1)',
              borderWidth: 1
          };

    var dataset = [];
    dataset.push(entranceDataset);

      var exitDataset = {
                label: 'Male',
                type: 'bar',
                yAxesID : "y-axis-1",
                data: male,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                borderWidth: 1
            };

      dataset.push(exitDataset);

    var ctx = $('#enrollcanvas');

    mainThroughputChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: year,
            datasets: dataset
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes : [{
                  gridLines : {
                        display : false
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Year'
                      }
                }]
            },

        }
    });
</script>
```

Laravel Controller and query

```
$female = Enroll::select(DB::raw("SUM(tot_enroll) as count"))
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('sy'))
            ->groupBy(DB::raw("(sy)"))
            ->where('gender','=', 'Female')
            ->get()->toArray();
            $female = array_column($female, 'count');

  $male = Enroll::select(DB::raw("SUM(tot_enroll) as count"))
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('sy'))
            ->groupBy(DB::raw("(sy)"))
            ->where('gender','=', 'Male')
            ->get()->toArray();
             $male = array_column($male, 'count');

return view('home')
        ->with('female',json_encode($female,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK))
        ->with('male',json_encode($male,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
```

Blade Page

```
<canvas id="enrollcanvas" name="enrollcanvas" height="280" width="600"></canvas>
```

Actual Bar Chart Result

[image: Bar Chart]

Database Table where the bar chart is based from

[image]

Comment: @IMRUP can you fix this too. I found you answered a post almost the same with my problem but I tried to modify mine but I can't follow it. This is the link of the post you answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973292/chart-js-bar-chart-load-data-based-on-label I hope this comment will reach you. I need this please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with mismatched data of `$female` and `$male` with JS year variable.

```
var year = ['2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020'];
var female = <?php echo $female; ?>;
var male = <?php echo $male; ?>;
```

Pass the '0' if `$female` OR `$male` doesn't have value for each year(Let's say 2000). So your `$female` and `$male` should be like:

```
var year = ['2000','2001','2002','2003', '2004'...];
var female = ['0','34', '0','65', '54',...];
var male = ['0','75', '0','34', '0',...];
```

### Update

Try this below code with full snippet of controller side. Replace  `enroll` with your database table name into this query.

```
$rsltEnrollData = DB::table('enroll')->selectRaw('sy as sy, gender, SUM(tot_enroll) as count')
->groupBy('sy')
->orderBy('sy')
->get();

$arrFemale = array();
$arrMale = array();
$arrYearData = array();
foreach($rsltEnrollData as $key => $objEnrollData){

    if(!isset($arrYearData[$objEnrollData->sy])){
        $arrYearData[$objEnrollData->sy]['Male'] = 0;
        $arrYearData[$objEnrollData->sy]['Female'] = 0;
    }
    $arrYearData[$objEnrollData->sy][$objEnrollData->gender] = $objEnrollData->count;
    $arrFemale = $arrYearData[$objEnrollData->sy]['Female'];
    $arrMale = $arrYearData[$objEnrollData->sy]['Male'];
}
```

### Debug

```
foreach($rsltEnrollData as $key => $objEnrollData){
 print('<pre style="color:red;">');
 print_r($objEnrollData);
 print('</pre>');
}
exit;
```

Comment: Yes, I too look it this way but this is only possible when I manually assigned values... my problem is, the data are from my database so the result is dependent from the content of my table where some years have no data... How can I handle this so that I can arrive to the same logic above as you have explained.

Comment: @ResnefImmatong: Check *UPDATE* from my answer

Comment: I get this error Undefined property: stdClass::$gender, 4th line from the last code you shared

Comment: `dd($rsltEnrollData);`, check for gender

Comment: where will i put this and how to check?

Comment: before `$arrFemale = array();` line

Comment: $arrYearData[$objEnrollData->sy][$objEnrollData->gender] = $objEnrollData->count;
                dd($rsltEnrollData);
                $arrFemale = $arrYearData[$objEnrollData->sy]['Female'];
                $arrMale = $arrYearData[$objEnrollData->sy]['Male'];

Comment: sorry I placed it on the wrong place.. Now I get result  Collection {#679 ▼
  #items: array:30 [▶]
}

Comment: Now I get 30 in array, does this mean the years in my tabale because I have 2001-2030 years in my table... Now how can I pass this data to my JS script?

Comment: Please check that collection having the gender column OR not. this is not the solution...

Comment: Yes, I now get result array:30. Now how can I get these arrays and pass to my script? Like var female = <?php echo $female; ?>;
var male = <?php echo $male; ?>;

Comment: provide me complete result please, array:30 means what?

Comment: The array:30 means all the years in my table in column sy. from 2001 to 2030... I expanded the console result and see these years from index 0 - 29. index 0 contains 2001 until index 29 contains 2030

Comment: Check *DEBUG* from my answer, make change as given and let me know what it print?

Comment: Collection {#679 ▼
  #items: array:30 [▶]
}

Comment: @ AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd This is the result stdClass Object
(
    [sy] => 2001
)
stdClass Object
(
    [sy] => 2002
)
stdClass Object
(
    [sy] => 2003
) .... and so on until 2030

Comment: only `[sy]` OR along with gender?

Comment: But based on query it should return count and gender as well. Re check the query with mine answer...

Comment: @ AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd I copied your answer as is.. I only changed the table name..

Comment: Ok, change get() to toSql() and check the query by print `$rsltEnrollData`

Comment: @ AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd still not getting the gender result.

Comment: this is what i get after changing get to tosql() : "select sy as sy from 'tblname' group by 'sy' order by 'sy' asc"

Comment: Hi, can you please give me a followup answer to my problem? :)

Comment: @ AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd so how sir?

Comment: @ResnefImmatong: Check the latest query from `UPDATE`, execute it and let me know the result with `toSql()`

Comment: @ AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd result tosql() : "select sy as sy from 'tblname' group by 'sy' order by 'sy' asc"

Comment: Twice check as my query with select statement like:  `sy as sy, gender, SUM(tot_enroll) as count` and result of toSql doesn't match with this....

Answer (score 0):

this is a snippet of the script in my project. maybe a little different, but maybe someone needs it. and hope it helps in configuring chart js with laravel and database

**JAVASCPT**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            var statistics_chart = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
            fetch("{{url('chart')}}")
            .then(response =>response.json())
            .then(json=>{
                var myChart = new Chart(statistics_chart, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: json.labels,
                        datasets: json.dataset,
                    },
                    options: {
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                gridLines: {
                                    // display: false,
                                    drawBorder: false,
                                    color: '#f2f2f2',
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    stepSize: 10000,
                                }
                            }],
                            xAxes: [{
                                gridLines: {
                                    display: false,
                                    tickMarkLength: 15,
                                }
                            }]
                        },
                    }
                });
            })
        });
```

**Controller**

```
public function chart()
{
    $data = Kas::select([
        DB::raw("SUM(debit) as total_debit"),
        DB::raw("SUM(kredit) as total_kredit"),
        DB::raw("MONTH(created_at) as bln"),
        // DB::raw("YEAR(created_at) as year")
    ])
    ->whereYear('created_at', 2022)
        ->groupBy([
            'bln'
        ])
        ->orderBy('bln')
        ->get();

    $arrBln = [1 => 'Jan','Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Agu', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Des'];
    $totalD = $totalK = [];
    foreach ($data as $tot) {
      $totalD[$tot->bln] = $tot->total_debit;
      $totalK[$tot->bln] = $tot->total_kredit;
    }

    foreach ($arrBln as $month =>$name){
        if(!array_key_exists($month, $totalD)){
            $totalD[$month]= 0;
        }
        if(!array_key_exists($month, $totalK)){
            $totalK[$month]= 0;
        }
    }

    ksort($totalD);
    ksort($totalK);

    return[
        'labels' => array_values($arrBln),
        'dataset' => [
            [
                'label' => 'Pemasukan',
                'data' => array_values($totalD),
                'borderWidth'=> 2,
                'backgroundColor'=> 'rgba(63,82,227,.8)',
                'borderWidth' => 0,
                'borderColor' =>'transparent',
                'pointBorderWidth' => 0,
                'pointRadius' => 3.5,
                'pointBackgroundColor' => 'transparent',
                'pointHoverBackgroundColor' => 'rgba(63,82,227,.8)',

            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Pengeluaran',
                'data' => array_values($totalK),
                'borderWidth'=> 2,
               'backgroundColor' => 'rgba(254,86,83,.7)',
                'borderWidth' => 0,
                'borderColor' =>'transparent',
                'pointBorderWidth'=> 0,
                'pointRadius'=> 3.5,
                'pointBackgroundColor'=> 'transparent',
                'pointHoverBackgroundColor'=> 'rgba(254,86,83,.8)',

            ],
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).