# Create a dynamic Bar graph using Chart.js where data is from database

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

I have been working on this issue a week and more but until now I am not able to achieve the right output for this.

I am working an online system where the data I project is from a database. I have a table for enrollment records in my database. Using Chart.js, I wanted to show a dynamic bar graph of the yearly enrollment. The bar graph works perfectly but it shows inaccurate result where the count does not match with the right year.

I noticed, that this happens because when a year is with no data, the other year fills this year, making the result wrong.

What will I do so that it will ignore empty year data or just set it to zero. I hope you can understand my problem, because I have been searching solutions about this but I can't find the right answer.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script>
    var year = ['2000','2001','2002', '2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020'];
    var female = <?php echo $female; ?>;
    var male = <?php echo $male; ?>;

    var entranceDataset = {
                  label: 'Female',
                  type: 'bar',
                  yAxesID : "y-axis-1",
                  data: female,
                  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 204, 0, 0.2)',
                  borderColor: 'rgba(0, 204, 0,1)',
                  borderWidth: 1
              };

        var dataset = [];
        dataset.push(entranceDataset);

          var exitDataset = {
                    label: 'Male',
                    type: 'bar',
                    yAxesID : "y-axis-1",
                    data: male,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1
                };

          dataset.push(exitDataset);

        var ctx = $('#enrollcanvas');

        mainThroughputChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: year,
                datasets: dataset
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes : [{
                      gridLines : {
                            display : false
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Year'
                          }
                    }]
                },

            }
        });
  </script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to take out "2000" in years string?

Comment: and what is the $male and $female value?

Comment: Check this [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45708632/4939915)

Comment: Why cant you send the years that contain data alone from PHP like what you have done for male and female, then you will get the proper data for the correct years, do you need all the years to display even if there is no data for that year?

Comment: @ Naren Murali yes i need years from 2001 until 2030.

Comment: @ResnefImmatong you didnt answer my question for whether you can send the years having data from the backend. then we can just do a merge with all the rows and the rows actually having data. Is that possible? based on the case, it would be correct to send it in the below format [{"year": 2010, "male": 123, "female": 1234}, {"year": 2011, "male": 1253, "female": 12354}] so that we can prepare the arrays for plotting with all the years.

Comment: @Naren Murali yes, that is what i am trying to get an array of year with corresponding count of female and male. can you give me give the better query to get the data. Ignoring the empty years. But the chart.Js cant give me correct data when one or more year is empty. So instead of setting a constant array value of years, how can i set the labels to be the years only available in the backend.

Comment: @ResnefImmatong That is a totally different region you need to raise another question in SQL I guess